# Chain method grouping and calculating differences in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, methods, method-chaining

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'glob_order': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    'trans': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'chain': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'date': ['1/08/2023', '2/08/2023', '3/08/2023', '4/08/2023', '5/08/2023', '6/08/2023', '7/08/2023', '8/08/2023', '9/08/2023', '10/08/2023', '11/08/2023']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'date' column to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

print(df)
```

I want to perform two operations:

- Group the DataFrame by the 'trans' and 'chain' columns and select the very first row from each group.
- Create a new column named 'delta' that represents the difference in days between the current date and the previous date within each group.

I tried the following code:

```
(df
.groupby(['trans', 'chain'])
.first()
.assign(
 delta=lambda x: (x['date'] - x['date'].shift(1)).dt.total_seconds() / (60*60*24),
 ).reset_index()
 )
```

However, the output I'm getting is not as expected. It seems to insert NaNs in the first delta calculation for each individual group, which is not what I want

| trans | chain | glob_order | date | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 2023-08-01 | NaN |
| A | 2 | 3 | 2023-08-03 | 2.0 |
| B | 1 | 5 | 2023-08-05 | 2.0 |
| B | 2 | 7 | 2023-08-07 | 2.0 |
| C | 1 | 8 | 2023-08-08 | 1.0 |
| C | 2 | 10 | 2023-08-10 | 2.0 |

I'd like to understand why this is happening and what I need to do to get the desired output.

This is my desired output

| trans | chain | glob_order | date | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 2023-08-01 | NaN |
| A | 2 | 3 | 2023-08-03 | 2.0 |
| B | 1 | 5 | 2023-08-05 | Nan |
| B | 2 | 7 | 2023-08-07 | 2.0 |
| C | 1 | 8 | 2023-08-08 | Nan |
| C | 2 | 10 | 2023-08-10 | 2.0 |

I am seeking a solution using a method similar to chaining for clarity and readability since I'm very new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want:

- as first step group by `"trans"`/`"chain"`, get first row
- as second step group by `"trans"` and get difference between days

I don't think simple chaining is possible, but you can use `:=` operator (but I recommend, for readability, to split it two separate commands):

```py
df = (df := df.groupby(["trans", "chain"], as_index=False).first()).assign(
    delta=df.groupby("trans")["date"].diff().dt.days
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  trans  chain  glob_order       date  delta
0     A      1           1 2023-08-01    NaN
1     A      2           3 2023-08-03    2.0
2     B      1           5 2023-08-05    NaN
3     B      2           7 2023-08-07    2.0
4     C      1           8 2023-08-08    NaN
5     C      2          10 2023-08-10    2.0
```

Comment: Hey Andrej! I remember you helped me out in other question thnks so much!!! yes you are correct i forgot that there was later a gropying by Trans alone as a second step could you please explain what does the : = do?, and why you se as_index=False I swear Python is full of mysteries thanks a lot my man

Comment: @R_Student I've added `as_index=False` to the first `.groupby` to not call the `.reset_index()` afterwards.

Comment: To use the best of both answers, I'd go with your approach and a lambda in the `assign` (`delta=lambda d: d.groupby("trans")["date"].diff().dt.days`), the walrus is a bit weird here. It would be unpractical if you had a long chain of commands.

Answer (score 2):

use `assign` with groupby & lambda func.

```
(df.groupby(['trans', 'chain']).first()
   .assign(delta=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0)['date'].diff().dt.days)
   .reset_index())
```

output:

```
   trans    chain   glob_order  date        delta
0   A       1       1           2023-08-01  NaN
1   A       2       3           2023-08-03  2.0
2   B       1       5           2023-08-05  NaN
3   B       2       7           2023-08-07  2.0
4   C       1       8           2023-08-08  NaN
5   C       2       10          2023-08-10  2.0
```

Comment: Oh gosh this is so cool could you please explain the x.groyby level 0? what is that your code does work!

Comment: First, run the code `df.groupby(['trans', 'chain']).first()`. Then, you use group by index with level=0(`trans`) in the results.